# Meaning of 'I'm not saying that' in this paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is [a quote](https://genius.com/Jd-salinger-the-catcher-in-the-rye-chap-1-annotated) from 'The Catcher in the Rye' of J. D. Salinger.

> They're quite touchy about anything like that, especially my father.
> They're nice and all--*I'm not saying that*--but they're also touchy as
> hell. Besides, I'm not going to tell you my whole goddam autobiography
> or anything.

I think what Salinger wanted to say is his parents are touchy.

But he doesn't want to criticize his parents. So he first negates the fact

> I'm not saying that they're also touchy as hell.

and then going on to tell the truth that they are touchy.

> but they're also touchy as hell

But I am not sure if my understanding is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character speaking those words was named Holden. Holden speaks in a careless, imprecise style. This style increases the guesswork that a reader must do to understand what Holden meant to say. Here's what I think that Holden meant in this case.

ORIGINAL LANGUAGE

1. My parents would have about two hemorrhages apiece if I told anything pretty personal about them.
2. They're quite touchy about anything like that, especially my father.
3. They're nice and all--***I'm not saying that***--but they're also touchy as hell.

MY PARAPHRASE

1. My parents would get very upset if I told you very personal information about them.
2. That sort of thing bother both of my parents, especialy my father.
3. This might make you suspect that my parents have something to hide, such as cruelty; but you would be wrong to suspect that. My parents are kind, and ***I am not saying that they are cruel***; they are just very private.

Comment: I agree on Holden's imprecise style as part of the character Salinger created (and please be sure you don't confuse Holden Caulfield with J. D. Salinger). I took it to mean that he was "not saying" anything about his parents being anything other than "nice and all". What he meant by that, well, it's difficult to say, and difficult enough to say whether he meant anything.  The things that he is saying could be taken to sound negative, and he wants to reassure the listener/reader that he doesn't mean to be negative about his parents for their privacy preferences.